# When do we surrender a prisoner?

Tags: sources-mekorot

To the best of my recollection...

When bandits surround a city and demand that the inhabitants give them a specific person, we give them that person (because he is dead anyway and the rest may survive).

When they ask for one arbitrary person, we do not (because "his blood is not redder").

1. Where in Shas is this discussed?
2. What do we do if the bandits demand an arbitrary person from a proper subset (e.g., "any red-headed man" or "a relative of Ploni")?
3. Why do we not cast lots when the bandits do not demand a specific individual?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83099/472 (see the last paragraph of my answer there).

Comment: It's a Mishna in Terumot

Comment: @DoubleAA: cannot be. I never learned Terumot.

Comment: @sds Could be that you read something which quoted Mishnah Terumot, though.

Comment: יבמות דף נג  תוספות  ד"ה שאנסוהו

Comment: Sanhedrin 74a, Yoma 82b

Comment: Sanhedrin 74a (bottom) has "redder blood" but not in the context I need. I don't have Yoma and Yevamot at hand... Thanks.